# ssrs hide column based on parameter - column visibility greyed out

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, visibility

I am trying to hide a column for specific year groups if not the year group selected in the parameter.

For example, if you are running the report for students in Year 9, you don't need to see Year 7 target, Year 8 target etc. the only column you need is Year 9.

However, if I select my column for Year 9 target and right click, column visibility is greyed out.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the group properties / Visibility tab you can _Show or hide a group based on an expression_.

Comment: show us some code so we can see what you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Report Builder will prevent you hiding columns that are to the left of the double dashed lines in a matrix. See the below - the 2 left most columns cannot be hidden. This (at least, so I understand) is basically because they're required to be visible to render the rest of the table properly when you have row groupings set up.

[image: Tablix]

The fact that you're getting this issue implies a problem with your row groupings, or possibly the position of the Target column in your report. In my example the lowest grouping level is "Learner" - I would expect the target columns to be at that level.